# Selenium: Can't scroll to click element that is not visible because of thread error: element is not visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to click an element that is not visible and needs to be scrolled down to be visible. To fix this, I have tried to use javascript executor and action, but they do not work because before even scrolling, I get a thread error saying the element is not visible. I have made sure that the xpath to the element is correct and verified the code works with elements that are visible without the need to scroll.

```
<div class="product-grid-item clearfix" data-alpha="LOG ON T-SHIRT BLACK" data-price="4800" data-i="27">

 <a href="/products/8r9ya45zmdwz" class="product-link">

<img src="[//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0923/4190/products/Palace-2019-Autumn-T-Shirt-Log-On-black-1336\_200x200\_crop\_center@2x.jpg?v=1565334138](//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0923/4190/products/Palace-2019-Autumn-T-Shirt-Log-On-black-1336_200x200_crop_center@2x.jpg?v=1565334138)" alt="LOG ON T-SHIRT BLACK" class="img">

  </a>

 <div class="product-info">

<a href="/products/8r9ya45zmdwz" class="product-link">

<h3 class="title">LOG ON T-SHIRT BLACK</h3>

</a>

<div class="price">

<span class="prod-price">$48</span>
</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I have tried javascript executor and action

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-alpha='" + productName + "' and @class='product-grid-item clearfix']")); //error occurs at this line

int elementPosition = element.getLocation().getY();
String js = String.format("window.scroll(0, %s)", elementPosition);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(js);
element.click();
```

and

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@data-alpha='" + productName + "' and @class='product-grid-item clearfix']")); //error occurs at this line
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(element);
builder.click();
builder.build().perform();
```

Error message:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@data-alpha='WINDOWLICKER HOOD GREY MARL' and @class='product-grid-item clearfix']"}
```

Comment: The error message you posted doesn't state that the element isn't visible, it states that the element can't be found. Are you sure your locator is correct? Have you checked to see if the element is in an IFRAME? Have you tried adding a wait?

Comment: @JeffC I've tried all those things and I am pretty sure my locator is correct because it works when I manually scroll down to the element.

Comment: If possible then try to provide full code with the HTML screenshot. It would be better to understand the code and can try to find the solution. besides this, try to use some jQueries method to scroll the page by percentage or can scroll full page once to verify the things.

Comment: @Vishal I don't think I am scrolling past it. The error occurs at driver.findElement(), so it doesn't even scroll

Answer (score 1):

Try use `WebDriverWait` and change the locator with `contains`, may contain space.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(@data-alpha,'" + productName.trim() + "') and @class='product-grid-item clearfix']")));

scroll here....
```

Comment: if I use wait.until(), wouldn't it keep waiting so it wouldn't get to scroll?

Comment: The `WebDriverWait` for make sure the element exist, then do scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The element seems to be a *dynamic* element and as you mentioned that the *element that is not visible and needs to be scrolled down to be visible* so you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *WebDriverWait* and *ExpectedConditions* and `elementToBeClickable()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-grid-item clearfix' and contains(@data-alpha, 'LOG ON T-SHIRT BLACK')]//a[@class='product-link' and contains(@href, 'products')]/img[contains(@src, 'shopify')]"))).click();
  ```
- Using *WebDriverWait* and *ExpectedConditions* and `elementToBeClickable()` through *Actions*:

  ```
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-grid-item clearfix' and contains(@data-alpha, 'LOG ON T-SHIRT BLACK')]//a[@class='product-link' and contains(@href, 'products')]/img[contains(@src, 'shopify')]")))).click().build().perform();
  ```